# Getting this error in an ASP.NET Core application with API/GUI Sections

Tags: .net, api, .net-core

I am receiving an error when I launch my project (only on the API side) I am using multiple startup projects.

I think it is to do with conflicting .Net Core Frameworks in the project, but I'm not sure how to fix this

Here is the error I get on the API launch

"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing that dll.  The easiest way to fix it would be installing this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.2.2

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go and update